# Using a eigenvector to figure out the kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

We have the linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ of wich matrix from a basis $B$ to a basis $B'$ is
$$A=M(f;B,B')=\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1& 0&0\\
-2&0&4&4\\
1&1&1&0\\
0&1&3&2 \end{bmatrix}$$
In the question we're told that $(2,-2,0,1)$ is an eigenvector of A, and asked to determine the kernel of A. We can just solve the homogenous system $Av=0_{\mathbb{R}^4}$, but I would like to know how I can use the eigenvector fact to arrive at the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(2,-2,0,1)$ lies in the kernel of $A$ and the last three columns of $A$ are easily seen to be linearly independent. Therefore by the Rank–nullity theorem,which states that for a linear map $f:V \longrightarrow W, dim(V)=dim(\mathrm{im} f)+dim(\ker(f))$, the kernel of $A$ is the span of $(2,-2,0,1)$.